# Why is .apply / .map only running against the first column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

All!

I have two [2] `pd.DataFrames`: **df_colors** [20,3] and **df_master** [200,13].

I am attempting to update the values for each *item* in each *row*.

`df_colors.head(5)`

| COLOR | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| WHITE | 0 |
| BLACK | 1 |
| GREEN | 0 |
| YELLOW | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| BLUE | 0 |
| RED | 1 |

`df_master.head(5)`

| color_0 | color_1 | color_2 | color_3 | color_4 | ... | color_12 | color_13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RED | GREEN | YELLOW | PINK | NONE | ... | NONE | NONE |
| BLUE | BLACK | WHITE | GREEN | PINK | ... | RED | ORANGE |
| RED | NONE | NONE | NONE | NONE | ... | NONE | NONE |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| BLACK | WHITE | ORANGE | NONE | NONE | ... | NONE | NONE |
| PURPLE | ORANGE | GREEN | WHITE | BLUE | ... | RED | NONE |

```py
def fun2(x):
  _y1 = df_colors[df_colors.COLOR==x]
  
  if _y1.size > 0:
    _y1 = _y1.values[0][1]
  else:
    continue
  return _y1

col_names = list(df_master.columns)
dat1 = df_master[col_names] = df_master[col_names].map(lambda x: fun(2) if isinstance(x, str), else x)

dat1.head(3)
```

| color_0 | color_1 | color_2 | color_3 | color_4 | ... | color_12 | color_13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] | NONE | ... | NONE | NONE |
| 0 | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] | ... | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] | Empty DataFrame Columns: [COLOR,CODE] |
| 1 | NONE | NONE | NONE | NONE | ... | NONE | NONE |

**What I was expecting**:

| color_0 | color_1 | color_2 | color_3 | color_4 | ... | color_12 | color_13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NONE | ... | NONE | NONE |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | NONE | NONE | NONE | NONE | ... | NONE | NONE |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | NONE | NONE | ... | NONE | NONE |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | WHITE | 0 | ... | 1 | NONE |

Answer (score 0):

Your current logic is unclear, but if you want to replace the colors by their code why not just use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) (`applymap` for older pandas version):

```
out = df_master.map(df_colors.set_index('COLOR')['CODE'].get)
```

Output:

```
   color_0  color_1  color_2  color_3  color_4  color_12 color_13
0      1.0      0.0      0.0      NaN      NaN       NaN     None
1      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      NaN       1.0     None
2      1.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN     None
3      1.0      0.0      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN     None
4      NaN      NaN      0.0      0.0      0.0       1.0     None
```

Comment: thank you. This still only updates the first column ('color_0'). The rest of the values are set to `None` (color_1:color_13)

Comment: I should note, running functions like .lower(), does apply as expected (changing every item within the df to lower.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example, maybe your keys are not matching (extra spaces?)